# three.js player movement bug

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js, quaternions

after working for a while on getting camera movement all settled, It's time to add movement into my three.js project. Firstly I just tried using `camera.translateZ(movementSpeed)`, but that makes the camera fly, and I want to restrict movement to the x and z axes. Basically I planned on simply finding the z and x velocity using the cosine and sine of the camera's y rotation. This works perfectly fine for the first half of rotating, but it stops during the second half. Is there a better way to do this, or can I somehow fix it?

You can find a fiddle for it at http://jsfiddle.net/zLa78yqw/2/, do note that I added a ball that shows where going forward would land the camera.

My code for figuring out delta z and x is:

```
 var zvel=Math.cos(camera.rotation.y);
 var xvel=Math.sin(camera.rotation.y);
 testBall.position.z=camera.position.z-zvel*2;
 testBall.position.x=camera.position.x-xvel*2;
```

Please help, I've been stuck on this for a while.

TLDR: I need help making an object in 3js move forward, without moving up.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is not camera.rotation.y, but instead the azimuth of the camera's world direction.

```
vector = camera.getWorldDirection();
azimuth= Math.atan2(vector.x,vector.z);
```